# How to print a symbol `n` times using a `for` loop, in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, char, putchar

Is it possible to print '#' `n` times using a `for` loop in C?

I am used to `print(n * '#')` in Python.

Is there an equivalent for that in C?

```
for(i=0; i < h; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", i * h);
}
```

Comment: Print the *single character* in a loop. As in `printf("#");` inside the loop.

Comment: A more interesting challenge would be to print it _n_ times without using a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output the symbol `'#'` `n` times in the for loop there is no need to create dynamically a string. It will be inefficient.

Just use the standard function `putchar` like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    putchar( '#' );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char c = '#';
    
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1  || n == 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ )
            {
                putchar( c );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
#########
##########

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

If you need to send the symbol in a file stream then use the function

```
int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);
```

instead of `putchar`.

Comment: The question was how to construct a string of some sub-string repeated n times, not how to print a character n times.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 Reread the question "how to print a symbole # for exemple n times using for loop in c"

Comment: Hmm. The post has been edited. Sorry. Still, the core of the question is asking for a replacement for Python's `"foo" x 10" syntax for repeating a string.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 The post has been edited after looking at other answer, I have been observing this guy he is one copy cat.

Comment: @fedibenothmen Two for loops similarly as I showed?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes pretty much the same except i didn't use some complex functions (as i am still a beginner )

Comment: @fedibenothmen In my answer there are no complex functions. I only provided a demonstrative program to show how in loop n symbols '#' can be outputted.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i just didn't understand the putchar that's why I said it was complex (for me) thanks for the help !

Comment: @fedibenothmen To close the question you should select the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible by any mechanism in standard C. If you want a string of some sub-string repeated n times, you will have to construct it yourself.

Simple example:

```
const char *substring = "foo";

// We could use `sizeof` rather than `strlen` because it's
// a static string, but this is more general.
char   buf[8192];
size_t len = strlen(substring);
char  *ptr = buf;

// Ideally you should check whether there's still room in the buffer.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    memcpy(ptr, substring, len);
    ptr += len;
}
*ptr = '\0';

printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `%.*s` format specifier.

```
int h = 10; //upper limit
char pat[h*h];

memset(pat, '#', sizeof pat);

for (int i=0;i<h;i++)
{
  printf("%.*s\n",i*h, pat);
}
```

output:

```
##########
####################
##############################
########################################
##################################################
############################################################
######################################################################
################################################################################
##########################################################################################
```

Please excuse me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Is this actually a standard format specifier? I was under the impression that it's an extension.

Comment: It's not listed in the man page for printf or here "http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf". I believe it is an extension.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 it is listed as part of it see `width` table.

Comment: Read it more carefully. That is only to specify the minimum width of the string for formatting.

Comment: @user3121023 Not quite. That specifies the maximum number of characters to print (unless a NUL is found earlier). You might use it to print a string that isn't NUL terminated. It does not print the string n times.

Comment: Yeah. I'm an idiot. For having proven I didn't really read the original code I'll just quietly show myself out of this thread.